# Which Event Triggered Just before footer block is rendered

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to add some html code before body end by observer because I will add as per some condition. so please suggest some event
which I can use for add html code. I want event that trigger just before footer block is rendered.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Maybe you take [the tour first](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also check [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Here's link to a list of Magento Events](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/).  If you see one that indicates it fires before the footer is rendered, use that.  Otherwise you'll probably need to research creating your own event/observer for that situation.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i used controller_front_send_response_before event and add my code from observer  by getting html dom object $response = $observer->getEvent()->getFront()->getResponse();
        $html = $response->getBody();